# Why is this git workflow causing issues?

Tags: git, egit

I'm trying to use git on a team project with one other person. I'm trying to use just the bare minimum as this is the first time the other person has used git. As such, we're both just committing to master. However, the issue that occurs is when we both commit

( O/M is origin/master A/M and B/M are people's individual master branches)

The issue that occurs is in the following situation,

```
O/M   -- ----
         /  \
A/M   --/    \
              \
B/M   ---- -----
```

A makes some changes and pushes them back to origin/master. At the same time, B makes some changes and pulls the changes from origin/master, committing if needed. After this point, B is unable to push the commits back to master.

As far as I understand, to get A's changes, B just needs to fetch and merge from master, which is done by git pull. However, after doing `git pull`, every time the attempt to push afterwards gives an error saying to read the note about fast forwards. The note about fast forwards in help just says to fetch and merge, which is why I don't understand why this isn't working.

Both A and B's master branches are set to track origin/master.

Comment: Sounds like B's history got altered with a rebase or something. Are you guys using Git from the command line, or a Git gui? I think GitHub for Windows does some weird stuff with syncing by doing rebases implicitly.

Comment: I'm (A) using the command line, while he's using EGit.

Comment: Ok, here's another question, does B just need to do another pull/fetch-merge before pushing?

Comment: No, git pull says Everything is up to date.

Comment: Is it possible to check if the sha ids on the commits match in yours and B's history?  If corresponding commits have identical shas, then the push should work, but if the shas are different when they shouldn't be, then Bs history definitely got altered.

Comment: You might want to check how B has egit configured to do pulls, [docs here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Fetching_from_other_Repositories). The docs say that "EGit can configure a tracking relationship so that subsequent pulls will fetch and then merge or rebase (depending on the configuration of this tracking relationship) the changes from the tracked upstream branch; see [Branching](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Branching) for details".  If you're proficient from command line and can help B, you might just want B to use command line from now on, instead of a Git gui.

Answer (score 1):

This workflow should absolutely work as described. use git log and gitk to compare the history A and B are seeing. It sounds like something is really fishy with the repositories